# Why does this syntax work over the other one with d3.json requests?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I don't understand why all the examples i find work with json requests like this:

```
d3.json("file.json", function(data){
   ..do something with data
});
```

..but when I had to implement it I had to use:

```
d3.json( "file.json", function(data){}).then(function(data){
    ..do something with data
)};
```

What is happening there? 
I'm running a live-server with node.

Comment: *Pssst* How long did it take you to notice that your callback function isn't being used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most probably because you're using `d3 v5` which has just been released and most of legacy examples are using `d3 v3` or `d3 v4`.

See [Changes in D3 5.0](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md).

The new v5 way of doing is indeed (quoting from the changelog):

```
d3.json("file.json").then(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

wherease before it would have been (v3, v4):

```
d3.json("file.json", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log(data);
});
```